# Global variables in python function app on Azure

Tags: python, azure, global-variables, azure-function-app

I have an Azure function app in which I need the current datetime (-3 hours) in several python functions.

To make sure each function uses the same time, I generate the datetime object globally before the function definitions, and late use it inside the functions:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

# get the current time in the correct timezone. Since triggers are executed based on UTC, we then again subtract
#   3 hours (just to be save) to end up with the correct day
current_time = datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
current_time -= timedelta(days=(3 / 24))

def _file_exists() -> bool:
    filename = current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d.csv')
    # ... further code


def main():
    save_as = '{path}/{filename}'.format(path=path_raw, filename=filename)
    # ... further code
```

I do not need to modify the contents, so no `global` keyword there.

However, when I publish this function to azure (Python 3.8, Linux), it parses the script and sets the `current_time` variable to the datetime of the upload and it is fixed for all subsequent executions (timerTrigger). For example, I uploaded my function yesterday, and since then the command `logging.warning(current_time)` in `main()` outputs `2020-04-14 08:31:05.003618+02:00`.

If I try this locally (Python 3.7, Windows, PyCharm) this works fine, even if I byte-compile the files manually:

```
python test.py    # 2020-04-15 11:30:36.426750+02:00
python test.py    # 2020-04-15 11:31:00.439632+02:00

python -m compileall .
python __pycache__/test.pyc # 2020-04-15 11:33:27.189967+02:00
python __pycache__/test.pyc # 2020-04-15 11:33:36.853601+02:00
```

Is this a bug on azure? And/or what is the best workaround? 
Is it related to (im)mutable types, and if so, has anyone a link that explains it for this case (I am aware of the behaviour in classes/function parameters)?

I think about defining it globally as `None`, and set the value in an `_init()` function in the script that is called somewhere in the script.

***Edit:*** After a few unsuccessful tries I found that

```py
# get the current time in the correct timezone. Since triggers are executed based on UTC, we then again subtract
#   3 hours (just to be save) to end up with the correct day
current_time = None


def _init_current_time():
    global current_time
    current_time = datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')) - timedelta(days=(3 / 24))

def main():
    _init_current_time()
    # main code
```

does the job. So far I *can* work with that, it just feels very.. dirty. So, continuing the question, is there a **proper** solution?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar kind of issue using a **Python Timer Triggered Azure Function**.

I **use a global variable that holds a timestamp** which will be used to create the folder structure of a blob that I upload e.g. `/year/month/day/hour`.

I **noticed that the values stay the same after an initial call** of the function meaning that if the function is triggered the next day the global timestamp still seems to hold the same value. Noticed that because the function wrote files in the wrong blobstorage folder.

For me **it looks as if these global variables are getting initialized only once and then live forever**. So the Azure Function Runtime never really "closes" and restarts the `__init__.py` it just triggers the main function.

**Before I used a HTTP Trigger and then I didn't had this issues. So in my case it seems just to be an issue for Timer triggerd azure functions.**

Maybe someone with deeper knowledge about the Azure Runtime might explain this behaviour a bit more detailed and why it happens?